# Visual Studio 2010 C# Form Project - Drag and Drop - best method?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop, draggable

My aim is to create an application whereby a user can drag a label from a tabbed container into some form of holding area - which had a ruler and a basic grid. I have consulted Google on the subject but the tutorials seem to involve dragging and dropping form components in design view.

The final aim is to then take my holding area and translate that into a .xml file - whereby each dropped element has an entry as follows:

[Dragged Component Name][X Co-ordinate][Y Co-Ordinate][Other Param's].

Any help with both aspects would be very much appreciated - this is just for a demonstration to a colleague.

Comment: Regarding the drag and drop - I have attempted to set a container to accept drag - but I have been unable to set any labels to "Draggable" - not sure how to proceed really...

Comment: In your labels, you need to handle mouse events. When you have detected that the control is being "dragged" you can use the mouse co-ordinates to update the location of your label as the mouse events fire. This will cause label control to move with the mouse i.e. be dragged.

Comment: Actually using a Label control is a problem, it behaves like at a control at runtime.  It has a Parent, it cannot have two parents at the same time.  Simplify it by dragging something that just *looks* like a label, a rectangle with text in it.  Or take advantage of the actual winforms designer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Comment: Might want to edit your question/tags to specify WPF or WinForms more clearly. It might greatly affect the nature of any proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163871.aspx

This link contains information on creating form designing forms looking exactly like Visual Studio Forms Designer. This way you may need to handle less situations than writing a forms designer with conventional methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.